# How to use dnlib library to get the instructions of all the methods?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, reflection, dnlib

I'm trying to use the [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/) library wich is part of the [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) project to load an assembly and get the **IL** instructions contained on the "body" of all the methods.

I've compiled an assmebly with this **VB.NET** source:

```
Public Class Main

    Public Sub testmethod(ByVal testparameter As String)
        MsgBox(testparameter)
    End Sub

    Public Class Test2

        Public Function testfunction(ByVal testparameter As String) As String
            Return testparameter
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

I know that the compiler modifies a lot of things, but I think that the method names (in this case) will not be modified, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Then I'm trying to retrieve those methods with this code:

```
Imports dnlib.DotNet
Imports dnlib.DotNet.Emit

Private Sub Test_Handler() Handles MyBase.Shown

    Dim asmResolver As New AssemblyResolver()
    Dim modCtx As New ModuleContext(asmResolver)

    ' All resolved assemblies will also get this same modCtx
    asmResolver.DefaultModuleContext = modCtx

    ' Enable the TypeDef cache for all assemblies that are loaded
    ' by the assembly resolver. Only enable it if all auto-loaded
    ' assemblies are read-only.
    asmResolver.EnableTypeDefCache = True

    Dim Assembly As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load("C:\WindowsApplication.exe")
    Assembly.Context = modCtx
    ' Use the previously created (and shared) context
    Assembly.Context.AssemblyResolver.AddToCache(Assembly)

    Dim Members As IEnumerable(Of MemberRef) = Assembly.GetMemberRefs

    For Each m As MemberRef In Members

        If m.IsMethodRef Then

            Dim Method As MethodDef = m.ResolveMethod

            If Method.HasBody Then

                Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
                With sb
                    .AppendLine(String.Format("Method Name: {0}", Method.FullName))
                    .AppendLine()
                    .AppendLine(String.Format("Method Signature: {0}", Method.Signature.ToString))
                    .AppendLine()
                    .AppendLine(String.Format("Method Instructions: {0}", Environment.NewLine &
                                              String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Method.Body.Instructions)))
                End With
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that the only documentation of this library that I've seen is the XML documentation file and some very basic examples on the dnlib site that helped me to write the code above, but I'm not sure how to resolve/retrieve those methods 'cause I'm not doinf it properly, the code above does not resolve any method that I've compiled (**testmethod** and **testfunction**), instead that it shows me a lot of constructors (.ctor) and other methods.

What I would like to do is just perform an iteration of all the methods (privated, public, etc) contained in the source that I've compiled regardless of the numer of Classes that the project has and regardless of what class contains an specific method, to get its instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are simply poking around in the Assembly, so all you get back is the stuff defined in `AssemblyInfo.vb`.  What you probably want to do is iterate the Types in the Assembly then drill into the members or properties defined for the one you are looking for.

This code should get you pointed in the right direction:

```vb
Dim modDef As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load("C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication1.exe")

For Each t As TypeDef In modDef.GetTypes
    'print the Type name
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name)

    ' stupid way to match a Type, but will work for demo purposes
    If t.FullName.StartsWith("ConsoleApplication1.Module1") Then

        For Each meth As MethodDef In t.Methods
            ' print the method name
            Console.WriteLine("     Method: {0}", meth.Name)
        Next

    End If
Next
```

The output looks like this, note that your methods are listed.

```
<Module>
MyApplication
MyComputer
MyProject
MyWebServices
ThreadSafeObjectProvider`1
InternalXmlHelper
RemoveNamespaceAttributesClosure
Module1
     Method: Main
     Method: testmethod
Test2
     Method: .ctor
     Method: testfunction
Resources
MySettings
MySettingsProperty
```

Comment: The code does not work for the WinForms source that I've provided (not a consoleapp):         `For Each t As TypeDef In modDef.GetTypes
            For Each meth As MethodDef In t.Methods
                If t.Name.Contains("test") Then
                    Debug.WriteLine("Method: {0}", meth.Name)
                End If
            Next
        Next`

Comment: oops, sorry, I've missed that I were trying to compare the type name (t.name.contains) and not the method name (meth.name.contains), it works perfect